# Traducción de "branding"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

¿Como traduciríais la palabra *branding* al español?

Tengo un límite de 16 caracteres e «imagen corporativa» o «imagen de marca» se pasan de longitud.

Comment: Así como planteas la pregunta es bastante confusa, pues presenta unas restricciones bastante alejadas de lo que es la lengua. Da algún contexto para que podamos afinar un poco más.

Comment: @fedorqui he dado 2 traducciones válidas pero demasiado largas, no se como puedo ser mas especifico. Es una aplicación informatica con limite para los literales, pero branding es branding

Comment: @JordiCastilla, usted menciona: `he dado dos traducciones válidas, pero demasiado largas`; si estas se encuentran en otra página, por favor edite su pregunta con referencias de las traducciones que menciona.

Comment: Con esas limitaciones y si es una aplicación dirigida a profesionales del ramo de la publicidad, *branding* entra dentro del vocabulario que el usuario final maneja y entiende. Quizás vendría bien algo más de contexto, del tipo ¿es un formulario? ¿Lo que escriba el usuario en el formulario será lo que obtenga como nombre personalizado en algún producto? ¿Se podría ello considerar «marca» a secas como alternativa aceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Con esas restricciones (en especial la de número de caracteres), y la falta de contexto sobre *dónde* va a ser usada a mi lo único que se me ocurre es

> Instaurar marca

Branding (que es un anglicismo que seguramente es perfectamente comprendido por aquellos que van a estar leyendo sobre *branding*) engloba varias cosas: crear una marca en imagen corporativa, mantenerla, posicionar la marca... (como seguro que ya sabes).

Como `crear marca` que es muy básico (y puede que no recoja todos los matices de *branding*) puede no ser del todo aplicable (no dices dónde va a ir el "rotulo"), yo optaría por una explicación tipo `creación de marca`, que de nuevo puede no englobar todo lo que *branding* es, pero es la definición más básica. Como se me pasa de caracteres<sup>*</sup> opté por sinónimos de "crear" e `instaurar` era de el que mejor se adaptaba, para mi gusto. `Establecer` podría valer, pero `establecer marca` son 17 caracteres y puede tener el matiz de que la marca ya está creada y que lo que se busca es sólo posicionarla.

<sup>*</sup> Tal vez sea posible hablar con alguien para ampliar esa restricción? Es por proponer otra solución un poco "out-of-the-box thinking", en caso de que a alguien se le ocurra un término genial pero se pase por un par de letras.